# This operation would create an incorrectly structured document

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

I am new to `XML` and tried the following but I'm getting an exception.  Can someone help me?

The exception is `This operation would create an incorrectly structured document`

My code:

```
string strPath = Server.MapPath("sample.xml");
XDocument doc;
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(strPath))
{
    doc = new XDocument(
        new XElement("Employees",
            new XElement("Employee",
                new XAttribute("id", 1),
                    new XElement("EmpName", "XYZ"))),
        new XElement("Departments",
            new XElement("Department",
                new XAttribute("id", 1),
                    new XElement("DeptName", "CS"))));

    doc.Save(strPath);
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Xml document must have only one root element. But you are trying to add both `Departments` and `Employees` nodes at root level. Add some root node to fix this:

```
doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("RootName",
        new XElement("Employees",
            new XElement("Employee",
                new XAttribute("id", 1),
                new XElement("EmpName", "XYZ"))),

        new XElement("Departments",
                new XElement("Department",
                    new XAttribute("id", 1),
                    new XElement("DeptName", "CS"))))
                );
```

Comment: They would may think about making this error message more explicit. Something like "XML document may have only one root element". Even knowing this fact it's hard to understand the issue by this error message alone.

Answer (score 12):

You need to add root element.

```
doc = new XDocument(new XElement("Document"));
    doc.Root.Add(
        new XElement("Employees",
            new XElement("Employee",
                new XAttribute("id", 1),
                    new XElement("EmpName", "XYZ")),
        new XElement("Departments",
            new XElement("Department",
                new XAttribute("id", 1),
                    new XElement("DeptName", "CS")))));
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was trying to add more than one XElement to xDocument which throw this exception. Please see below for my correct code which solved my issue

```
string distributorInfo = string.Empty;

        XDocument distributors = new XDocument();
        XElement rootElement = new XElement("Distributors");
        XElement distributor = null;
        XAttribute id = null;


        distributor = new XElement("Distributor");
        id = new XAttribute("Id", "12345678");
        distributor.Add(id);
        rootElement.Add(distributor);

        distributor = new XElement("Distributor");
        id = new XAttribute("Id", "22222222");
        distributor.Add(id);
        rootElement.Add(distributor);

        distributors.Add(rootElement);


 distributorInfo = distributors.ToString();
```

Please see below for what I get in distributorInfo

```
<Distributors>
 <Distributor Id="12345678" />
 <Distributor Id="22222222" />
</Distributors>
```